# Flutter ffi unable to execute function

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi

This is `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(app SHARED
            hello.cpp
            )
```

This is my `hello.cpp` file:

```cpp
extern "C" {

void init() {
    printf("Hello world");
   }
}
```

This is how I am trying to call this function from my flutter code:

```dart
final nativeLibrary = DynamicLibrary.open("libapp.so");
final function = nativeLibrary.lookup<NativeFunction<Void Function()>>("init").asFunction();
function();
```

This code has no problem in loading the library or finding the function but vm crashes when I try to call `function()` with

> error: unreachable code

How to fix this?

Comment: Two comments: ffi doesn't support `bool` - you would use an `int32_t` instead. In C init returns something, but your lookup is for a void function - maybe change init to return void.

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd suggest using a `plugin`-type project. Could you show more of the Dart code?

Comment: even after making it void, it gives the same error. And I'll try making it like a plugin. Maybe flutter links native libraries to itself as flutter itself is shipped as `libflutter.so`. I didn't think this earlier. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the suggestion is to keep your C/C++ source in the ios Classes folder and use a relative path in the cmake file. See: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop

Comment: I have a similar issue on flutter desktop app for macos. Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @RichardHeap Even i am facing a similar issue and I have logged a issue in the official Github repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62122

Comment: @GaneshRathinavel I don't remember but I think doing it in a plugin style worked for me. as Richard commented.